# Compare const char * to const char

Tags: programming, c

Using ArduinoJson I have assigned a value such as;

```
const char* id = root["id"];
```

in the original JSON id was "1"

```
if (strcmp(id, "1") == 0) {
    // this executes
}
```

I have an array of structs that I wish to compare the id against. The struct looks like;

```
typedef struct  {
   char id[2];
   ....
} Device;
```

I assign an id (1-9) into the struct id by

```
_cmd.id[0] = '0' + (++DevicesPtr);
_cmd.id[1] = '\0';
Devices[DevicesPtr-1] = _cmd;
```

where _cmd is of type Device. Devices is an array with up to 8 entries
Now I try to find a match in the devices using the JSON id

```
for (byte i = 0; i < DevicesPtr; i++) {
    if (strcmp(Devices[i].id, id) == 0) {
       // This code does not execute
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get a match I have also tried (Devices[i].id == id)

Comment: Strcmp is the way to go, but I'm not sure your code is giving away what the issue is, Mikaels answer is a more explicit version of what I imagine your code looks like. I presume you initialize DevicesPtr to 0 at some point? Mikael is also renaming your variables to more useful names another good idea : Could you post the code in full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
typedef struct  {
  char id[2];
  ....
} Device;

const int DEVICES_MAX = 8;
Device Devices[DEVICES_MAX];

for (int i = 0; i < DEVICES_MAX; i++) {
  Devices[i].id[0] = '1' + i;
  Devices[i].id[1] = 0;
  ...
}

for (int i = 0; i < DEVICES_MAX; i++) {
  if (!strcmp(Devices[i].id, id)) {
  ...
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a char and a string.. How can you compare apples and bananas?

Now, you have two ways to do your job.

1) do as @Mikael Patel suggests, so convert your `id`s into strings. This is fine because it will allow you to deal with multiple chars ids.

2) a more efficient way to do this (note that this works with just SINGLE CHARS IDS) is the following one:

```
if (strlen(id) == 1) {
    for (byte i = 0; i < DevicesPtr; i++) {
        if (Devices[i].id == id[0]) {
           // This code will execute if ids match
        }
    }
}
```

Note that id should be exactly 1 char long, otherwise the whole comparison as you thought is meaningless

With this solution you don't need multibyte id char in the struct definition, so you can just define

```
typedef struct  {
   char id;
   ....
} Device;
```

and, in the code,

```
_cmd.id = '0' + (++DevicesPtr);
Devices[DevicesPtr-1] = _cmd;
```

Comment: Actually this can be improved further. The id field in the struct is not needed as the index is a function of the value (i.e. index = id - '1'). The test is simply that the index must be in [0..last_device] and last_device in [0..MAX_DEVICES-1]. A search is not really required if the id is ['1'...'9'].